# Geting multiple variants by id using Admin API

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to get multiples variants by id through the Admin API? My query looks like this:

```
shop.myshopify.com/admin/variants.json?ids=350xxxx,355xxxx
```

The response however just returns me a really long list of variants... Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in Shopify. You need to get single product variant at a time in variant api.
i.e

```
/admin/variants/{id}.json
```

Comment: That seems extremely cumbersome, but the answer is the answer I suppose. Thanks for the help!